# Transform cannot be found

Tags: assets, image-transforms

I've got a Matrix field with an image. If I use a pre-defined transform that's defined in Assets everything works fine. However, I need to set a transform manually in the template but it keeps returning an error "The transform “wideCrop” cannot be found!". I have used transforms in templates all over the site that work fine so I'm puzzled why this particular one isn't working.

This is from an embedded template inside the entry:

```
{% for block in entry.contents %}
    {% for image in block.image %}          

        {% switch block.position %}
            {% case 'full' %}
                {% set wideCrop = { width: 940, height: 360, mode: 'fit' } %}
                <img class="full" src="{{ image.getUrl('wideCrop') }}">   
        {% endswitch %}

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around wideCrop.

```
<img class="full" src="{{ image.getUrl(wideCrop) }}">
```

[Details for why the difference in "template defined" transforms here:](https://craftcms.com/docs/image-transforms)

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't believe I missed the quote marks. Too much code, not enough sleep. :)